# Remove Dependencies - I don't want to install them

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, firefox, libreoffice

**PC Specs**

> OS : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 Bit

After **reinstalling** ubuntu back on my laptop, I installed `google-chrome-beta`,`virtualbox` and `opera-developer`, I decided to **remove** `LibreOffice` and `firefox. I typed following commands in terminal to remove these packages :

> sudo su
>
> apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
>
> apt-get clean
>
> apt-get autoremove

*Similar commands are given for removing firefox as well.*

Terminal gave me a long list of errors and suggested to use `sudo apt-get -f install`. So I typed that command and it said it need to **download 303 MB of archives**.*I typed 'No'.*

> Here are the list of archives or errors that terminal generated after executing `sudo apt-get -f install` : (Onedrive Link)
>
> > https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5F8FA3803E7E40D3!5364&authkey=!AJ45-JnuqSSk8fU&ithint=file%2ctxt

Please Help

I am really **new to linux**.

I just use Linux to run `virtualbox` , launch Windows XP VM and play Road rash or just to browse web using `Chrome` or `opera` or to retrieve my data from Windows partition - in case windows couldn't be started.

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall firefox with these steps

Open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run following command

`sudo apt-get purge firefox`

After that Delete `.mozilla/firefox/` in your home directory

Also Delete `.macromedia/` and `.adobe` in your home directory, these can contain "Flash Cookies" stored by the browser. The same is true, if applicable, for Silverlight (Moonlight) and other plugins, they can allow websites to store data on your computer.

After that delete `/etc/firefox/`, this is where your preferences and user-profiles are stored

Also delete `/usr/lib/firefox/`

Also delete `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/`

**Note :**

- Don't rely on this method if you've got sensitive information to protect! Deleting a file, in most cases, only means deleting a reference to it. The raw data will still be on your hard drive, and the proverbial bond-villain will be able to recover them. I'm only mentioning this *in case* it's applicable to anybody who reads this. The only way to *really* get rid of data, is to shred the hard drive to bits.

Comment: Firefox and Libreoffice - both were not removed. The main issue was not removing these applications , but was to remove the **dependencies errors** which is **stopping** me to remove these two applications , and add any new application.